# I can not change children's positions in animation clip in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I am creating an animation in unity3d and want to change children's positions.
But i can not

I trying to change value of transform.y of this object but when i press 'enter' value returns to standard

https://imgur.com/eeyqDdN
https://imgur.com/DCkcFYQ

Comment: Please add images directly to the question not in external links

Answer (score 1):

1. You are in avatar configuration so it won't work.
2. Press the red recording button next to the preview button.

Itzhak